# Show sorted results from loop

Tags: python, list, loops, sorting

I'm testing different models (classifiers) and I've created a list (that will contain model names) and then loop through it to print accuracy and cross validation score for each one of them. It works fine.

The thing I'd like to do is showing them **ordered by descending accuracy_score** (*metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)* in the code below). How do I do that easily?

Thanks a lot to anyone who'll be willing to help!

```
#create an array of models
models = []

models.append(("Random Forest",RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100, random_state = 0)))
#models.append(("Logistic Regression",LogisticRegression()))
models.append(("Naive Bayes",GaussianNB()))
models.append(("SVM",SVC()))
models.append(("Dtree",DecisionTreeClassifier()))
models.append(("KNN",KNeighborsClassifier()))
models.append(("Gradient Boosting",GradientBoostingClassifier()))


#measure the accuracy and show results per model
for name, model in models:
    # fit the model with x and y data
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    #Prediction of test set
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    kfold = KFold(n_splits=4)#, random_state=22)
    cv_result = cross_val_score(model, X_train, y_train, cv = kfold, scoring = "accuracy")
    print('\033[1m', name, '\033[0m')
    print('accuracy score is: \033[1m', metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred),'\033[0m')
    print('cross validation score is: ' ,cv_result,'\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
```

Comment: Could you please turn your code snippet into something that everyone can copy-paste and execute, by including the relevant `import ...` or `from ... import ...`?

Answer (score 2):

Append your scores to a new list, and then sort that list using the `.sort()` method, like so:

```
#create an array of models
models = []

models.append(("Random Forest",RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100, random_state = 0)))
#models.append(("Logistic Regression",LogisticRegression()))
models.append(("Naive Bayes",GaussianNB()))
models.append(("SVM",SVC()))
models.append(("Dtree",DecisionTreeClassifier()))
models.append(("KNN",KNeighborsClassifier()))
models.append(("Gradient Boosting",GradientBoostingClassifier()))

results = [] # New list to store results

#measure the accuracy and show results per model
for name, model in models:
    # fit the model with x and y data
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    #Prediction of test set
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    kfold = KFold(n_splits=4)#, random_state=22)
    cv_result = cross_val_score(model, X_train, y_train, cv = kfold, scoring = "accuracy")
    
    results.append((name, metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)))

    print('\033[1m', name, '\033[0m')
    print('accuracy score is: \033[1m', metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred),'\033[0m')
    print('cross validation score is: ' ,cv_result,'\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')

results.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse=True) # sort in-place

print(results) # print results
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Is it possible, instead of creating a new list, keeping the template I've created (the 3 prints with that formatting) and order directly those?

Comment: @StefanoPuccini  You could just call `.sort` on the list you've created with an appropriate score function as the `key` argument; but since your score `metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)` requires `y_pred`, you need to either store the score in a list, or store `y_pred` in a list.

Comment: @StefanoPuccini Or you could use `models.sort(key=lambda model: metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, model.predict(X_test)))` directly, but if you've already run `model.predict(X_test)` during the previous loop, then you're running it twice, which is a bit wasteful

Answer (score 1):

Rather than doing everything in the same big chunk of code inside the loop, I suggest to identify the different types of operations that you're doing and separate them into their own functions:

- Run the model, fit, predict, compute score;
- Sort the list;
- Print the model;

```py
import operator  # itemgetter

#create an array of models
models = []

models.append(("Random Forest",RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100, random_state = 0)))
#models.append(("Logistic Regression",LogisticRegression()))
models.append(("Naive Bayes",GaussianNB()))
models.append(("SVM",SVC()))
models.append(("Dtree",DecisionTreeClassifier()))
models.append(("KNN",KNeighborsClassifier()))
models.append(("Gradient Boosting",GradientBoostingClassifier()))

def run_model(m):
    name, model = m
    # fit the model with x and y data
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    #Prediction of test set
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    kfold = KFold(n_splits=4)#, random_state=22)
    cv_result = cross_val_score(model, X_train, y_train, cv = kfold, scoring = "accuracy")
    return (name, accuracy, cv_result)

def print_model(name, accuracy, cv_result):
    print('\033[1m', name, '\033[0m')
    print('accuracy score is: \033[1m', accuracy,'\033[0m')
    print('cross validation score is: ' ,cv_result,'\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')

results = sorted(map(run_model, models), key=operator.itemgetter(1))

for name, accuracy, cv_result in results:
    print_model(name, accuracy, cv_result)
```

*Disclaimer: Contrary to all best practices, I did not test this code before posting it, because the OP didn't provide example values for `X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test`, nor the relevant `import` to make their code work.*